# MVC 5 Custom error pages when using Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac

I'm trying to implement custom error handling in my asp.net mvc 5 application, using the same technique I have always used :

```
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            HandleApplicationErrors();
            Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
            Response.StatusCode = 500;          
        }
    }

private void HandleApplicationErrors(int? statusCode = null)
    {
        try
        {
            Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
            Response.Clear();

            HttpException httpEx = ex as HttpException;
            if (statusCode == null && httpEx != null) statusCode = httpEx.GetHttpCode();

            RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");

            switch (statusCode)
            {
                case 404:
                    routeData.Values.Add("action", "NotFound");
                    break;
                case 403:
                    routeData.Values.Add("action", "Forbidden");
                    break;
                default:
                    routeData.Values.Add("action", "ServerError");
                    break;
            }

            routeData.Values.Add("exception", ex);

            Server.ClearError();
            this.Server.ClearError();
            this.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            IController controller = new ErrorController();
            controller.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(this.Context), routeData));
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
            Response.StatusCode = 500;
        }
    }
```

This has worked just fine in the past, however in this application, I'm using Autofac, and it's throwing "Instances cannot be resolved and nested lifetimes cannot be created from this LifetimeScope as it has already been disposed." on the controller.Execute line. I've tried excluding the ErrorController from autofac registration (it doesn't have and constructor parameters anyway) and constructing it directly.

The controller code is pretty simple :

```
        private CustomErrorModel GetModel(Exception ex)
    {

        var model = new CustomErrorModel();
        model.RequestedUrl = Request.Url.OriginalString;
        model.ReferrerUrl = (Request.UrlReferrer == null || model.RequestedUrl == Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString) ? null : Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString;
        model.Exception = ex;
        return model;

    }

    public ActionResult ServerError(Exception ex)
    {
        var model = GetModel(ex);

        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        Response.Status = "500 Internal Server Error";
        return View(model);
    }
```

Anyone have any ideas on making this work?

Comment: What about the constructor for the error controller?  Is there one?  I am doing the exact same thing as you (including using Autofac) and don't have any issues.

Comment: the error controller doesn't have a constructor. This all works when not using autofac. Btw, I did also try with an empty default constructor.

Comment: Actually, I think your issue is that the `ServerError` action in your controller defines the parameter as `ex`, but in `HandleApplicationErrors` you're setting the route parameter for it as `exception`.  Change either so that they match, and it'll work as you expected.

Comment: @BrendanGreen you are correct, how did I not see that! I think somewhere along the line I reneamed the parameters, but forgot about the routedata. Add this as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help - answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing a very similar thing in my application, including using Autofac for dependency injection, and have not seen the same issues as you.

Looking closely at your `HandleApplicationErrors` method, I notice that your route data does not match the parameter that your `ServerError` action is expecting.

In `HandleApplicationErrors`, you are passing in a parameter named **`exception`**

In `ServerError`, you are expecting a parameter named **`ex`**

Updating the setting of the route data to match like so:

```
routeData.Values.Add("ex", ex);
```

will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, answering my own question here. I had a look at stack trace, and it seemed the exception was caused by mvc trying to use the container to find the model binder.. so I made my action methods parameterless and that solved it!

Posting code for reference here :

```
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        HandleApplicationErrors();
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        Response.StatusCode = 500;          
    }
}

private void HandleApplicationErrors(int? statusCode = null)
{
    try
    {
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
        Response.Clear();

        HttpException httpEx = ex as HttpException;
        if (statusCode == null && httpEx != null) statusCode = httpEx.GetHttpCode();

        RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");

        switch (statusCode)
        {
            case 404:
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "NotFound");
                break;
            case 403:
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "Forbidden");
                break;
            default:
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "ServerError");
                break;
        }

        //routeData.Values.Add("exception", ex);

        Server.ClearError();
        this.Server.ClearError();
        this.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        IController controller = new ErrorController();
        controller.Execute(new RequestContext(new     HttpContextWrapper(this.Context), routeData));
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
    }
}
```

and my controller method :

```
public ActionResult ServerError()
{
  HttpException ex = Server.GetLastError() as HttpException; 
  var model = GetModel(ex);
  Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
  Response.Status = "500 Internal Server Error";
  return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> "The request lifetime itself is disposed in the EndRequest event. You
>   can see this in the RequestLifetimeHttpModule which gets added
>   automatically to your pipeline when you reference the MVC integration.
>   Most likely there is a race condition where the Autofac event handler
>   is firing before your own EndRequest event handler. This is most
>   likely cropping up now simply because more recent Autofac integration
>   tries to make the registration of the module, etc. more seamless to
>   the developer so we register the module on pre-application-start. We
>   subscribe to the event first, so we get called first.
>
> Unfortunately, there's really not much to be done about it from the
>   Autofac side - EndRequest is the last event in the pipeline and we
>   have to dispose of the lifetime scope, so that's where it happens.
>
> If you are handling something at EndRequest that needs to be resolved,
>   it may be too late. Even in previous integrations, EndRequest would
>   have been a risk. For example, if you resolve an object that
>   implements IDisposable, the release of the lifetime scope on
>   EndRequest would dispose of the object and you'd be working with an
>   object in a bad state.
>
> I recommend trying to move the execution of your action to some time
>   before EndRequest. Alternatively, if you are 100% sure that the
>   objects in your chain aren't IDisposable, you could resolve the object
>   in an earlier event, store it in HttpContext.Items, and retrieve it
>   from there to use in your EndRequest handler."

font: https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/570

Comment: I somewhat confused by this, I'm not using the container or trying to resolve anything in the Application_Error handler.

Comment: So what is the recommended way to handle errors when using autofac then, since everything I read points to using the technique that I'm using.. it seems I have to choose, autofac or custom error pages?